# Beyond calculating just as an exercise, are there any other reasons to calculate an indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question, indefinite-integrals, education

Calculus textbooks often have us calculate indefinite integrals as exercises.  However, beyond calculating just as an exercise, are there any other reasons to calculate an indefinite integral?

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you want to emphasize solving *in*definite integrals vs. definite integrals. To state the obvious, if you don't know how to do the former, you won't be able to do the latter. So there's a good reason.

Beyond that evaluating indefinite integrals is key to solving many important differential equations.  ('Important' here means a few things, including many applications.)

Comment: but there are CADs that calculate these integrals much faster than humans...

Comment: Not all of them

Comment: I'm taking an MIT online course on Quantum Mechanics. An instructor just commented: *It is OK to use Mathematica, Wolfram alpha, Maple, or any other symbolic manipulator for doing integrals or long algebraic computations. It is important, however, that you use these tools only if you are sure you could do those integrals or calculations by yourself if you had to.* That sounds exactly right.